# Responsive 4 box grid from two to one columns

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, grid-layout

I'm a beginner in `css` and I have a little problem. I tested different methods to handle a responsive 4 `div` grid with `css`, and I failed.

I want to responsively arrange the 4 `div`s as an `grid` **with 2 columns** and, if the display is to narrow it should be floating **to a one column layout**.

Here is a sketch of the responsive grid:

[image: responsive grid from two to one columns]

Comment: if you want to make a responsive site as in your example my advice would be you should use bootstrap.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a simple **responsive grid with 4 div boxes** in plain *CSS* and *HTML* it aranges from two to one columns when the browser width becomes smaller :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/nK8XW/)** (resize the result window to see the effect)

Note that the `max-width` value on the `#container` is set to `450px` so that 2 blocks + their margin can fit by width in two colmuns.

When the widow is smaller than `450px` the width of the `#container` adapts to the window width and as the block can't fit anymore, they rearage to one column.

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #00CC99;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="block">1</div>
  <div class="block">2</div>
  <div class="block">3</div>
  <div class="block">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I really like the simplicity of this solution but if you need an entire page to be responsive it may be worth looking into a framework such as Bootstrap, Foundation, or just writing your own media queries.

Comment: @lhan16 the issue presented in the OP is simple so a simple solution can be found. This CSS is perfectly adaptable to a large project without becoming complicated and involving media quieries + I'm not shure the best way to learn CSS is to start with a framework, if you don't understand the *"behind the simplicity"* part of it it can become very confiusing.

Comment: Good point(s). I agree that it would be more important to learn the fundamentals of CSS first.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out **[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)**, and specifically their **[Grid System](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)**. You can easily accomplish what you want with that. Otherwise, you'd want to look into writing your own CSS **[Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)** to handle the different screen sizes.

Here's a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8A8ks/)** showing how this can be achieved using Bootstrap. Just drag the side of the Result container to make it smaller and you can see the blocks shift. This may need some tweaking but it should get you going.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
        <div class="block">1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
        <div class="block">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
        <div class="block">3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
        <div class="block">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the above code, I'm creating a Bootstrap Grid which uses 12 columns. You can specify the column width at different screen sizes, for example the class `col-sm-2` is saying use 2/12ths of the width for small screen sizes, then offset it 3 to center it. `col-xs-12` says to use the full width for extra small screen sizes (essentially moving each block to its own row for extra small screens). Note the `row` class as well which is also Bootstrap specific.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: This answer should have been a comment.

Comment: Somewhat, yes.  Although the only real answer to the question is to use a css framework that is designed for this scenario, like bootstrap.  Any other solution is going to be painful for the new developer.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is a great tool to do this as the above answerer said. Bootstrap allows you to position items in a grid layout (as you want). 
Another way to do this is create media queries in css that will take effect when the browser has a smaller or larger min-width.

I recommend using Bootstrap as all of the heavy lifting is done for you and you would just have to make small tweaks to ensure it looks like you want it to.